# How to change field permission for an object change event?

Tags: permissions, profile

How can we modify field permissions for the CustomObject__ChangeEvent fields via profile / permission sets? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is driven from the FLS of the User on the object changing. See [Change Data Capture Developer Guide - Field-Level Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_security_field.htm).

> Change Data Capture respects your org’s field-level security settings. Delivered events contain only the fields that a subscribed user is allowed to view. Before delivering a change event for an object, the subscribed user’s field permissions are checked. If a subscribed user has no access to a field, the field isn’t included in the change event message that the subscriber receives.

Comment: Thank you so much @TSmith!!!!!!